# How to write a x509 custom trust manager for validating the client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, x509certificate

I have a web application in which I am using Spring APIs to get the principal information in the certificate to check for valid user.

Assumption is that app server in which this is deployed contains the trust store that contains the CA's certificate and would validate the authenticity of the incoming request based on the requesting client's certificate and only then send it to the application.

And hence I was not validating the contents of the certificate and was just validating the Common Name (Principal) part in the certificate. Now if I want to write my own trust manager in the application that would validate the certificate against the CA's certificate, How do I acheive the same in Spring?

I know that I need to write custom truststore manager and override checkClientTrusted method, but dont know how to do it and how Spring should be configured to use this custom Trustmanager.. Do anybody know how to do this?

thanks

Nohsib

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trust manager for that. You just need to get hold of the certificate during a request. It is available as a request attribute: see the Servlet Secification.

The custom trust managers you customarily see on the Internet are in fact major security breaches, perpetrated by people who don't understand the problem or the implications of their radicslly inscure 'solution'.

Comment: thanks EJP, however it is the requirement. So if you know how to do that, kindly share. thanks.

Comment: @Nohsib It would be unprofessional of me to assist you in perpetrating a major insecurity and it would be unprofessional of you not to bring this to the attention of those who are specifying this requirement. Personally I would ask for a written instruction as defence against a future possible malpractice suit. It is that serious.